# Assembly - trying to write to file but access denied

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm, dosbox

I have a file which I need to write to from a "Buffer" in Data Segment, but when I try to write to the file with the DOS interrupt 21h 40h, it sets the Carry flag to 1, and the ax to 05 - which means access denied, what to do

Code Segment:

```
    proc scanScreen

        push offset Buffer
        call openFile
        mov [fileHandle], ax


        mov dx, [BMPX]
        mov di, [BMPY]
        mov cx, [BMPHeight]
        scanScreen_toBuffer:
            push cx
            mov si, offset graphicBuffer
            mov cx, [BMPWidth]
            scanScreen_toBuffer_line:
                push cx
                mov bh, 0
                mov cx, dx
                push dx
                mov dx, di
                mov ah, 0Dh
                int 10h
                mov [si], al
                inc si
                pop dx
                inc dx
                pop cx
            loop scanScreen_toBuffer_line
            mov ah, 40h                             -
            mov cx, [BMPWidth]                       |
            mov dx, offset graphicBuffer             |> HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            mov bx, [fileHandle]                     |  
            int 21h                                 -     
            pop cx
            mov dx, [BMPX]
            inc di
        loop scanScreen_toBuffer

        call closeFile
        ret
    endp scanScreen
```

Caller: (I scan the screen and print immediately to see if it stayed the same, which means it works)

```
            mov [BMPX],66
            mov [BMPY],38
            mov [BMPHeight], 5
            mov [BMPWidth], 12
            call scanScreen
            push offset Buffer
            call openFile
            mov [fileHandle], ax
            mov bx, [fileHandle]
            call showBMP
            call closeFile
```

data segment:

```
    BMPHeader       db HEADER_SIZE dup (RESET)
    BMPPalette      db AMOUNT_OF_COLORS * COLOR_SIZE dup (RESET)
    BMPX            dw ?
    BMPY            dw ?
    BMPWidth        dw ?
    BMPHeight       dw ?
    BMPMaxLine      db MAX_WIDTH dup (RESET)
    graphicBuffer   db MAX_WIDTH dup (RESET)

    Buffer          db "buffer.buf", RESET

    fileHandle      dw ?
```

Variables:

```
   RESET               equ 0
MAX_WIDTH           equ 320
AMOUNT_OF_COLORS    equ 256
HEADER_SIZE         equ 54
COLOR_SIZE          equ 4
```

Comment: Where's the code for `openFile`?  Are you opening the file with write permissions, or is it read only?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm wow, I'm so dumb, that what it was, I feel destroyed ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened the file I did not opened it for writing

from

```
        xor ax, ax
        mov ah, 3Dh
        int 21h
```

to

```
        mov al, 1
        mov ah, 3Dh
        int 21h
```